# Convert Bytes in KB

Tags: byte

I would like to "convert" a given value (in Bytes) to KBytes with more precision.

```
unsigned int test {

int out_bytes = 0;

out_bytes = InBytes / 1024;

return (out_bytes);

}
```

If InBytes is "139500", the out_bytes is actually 136. I would like to get 136,23. How can i do it?

Thank for help

Comment: Then out_bytes shoukd not be of type int. Int does not allow fractions and will round the result of InBytes/1024 to the next smaller integer value. Use double instead and please read about primitive types!